# Reading from a text file and executing contents in terminal

Tags: command-line, executable

Lets say I wanted to create a .txt file that had some commands in it.
Then from .txt file the contents are extracted to the terminal.
Is this even possible and does it have to be a .txt file? oh and I am running 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can be done. Just cd to the directory of the file in the terminal and type `chmod +x commands.txt`, and then `./commands.txt` runs commands in the file

No, it need not be `.txt`, extension doesn't matter

Comment: not on all sytems: `./myfile: command not found`

Answer (score 4):

You can also put one command per line in the text file (e.g. `my_commands.txt`), and then run them all as:

```
source my_commands.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file didn't even have an extension. I just created a plain file named `publish`, meant to hold commands to navigate into project folders and execute `npm publish`.

Example:

---

- It's content:

> cd kn-card && npm publish
>   cd ../kn-chart && npm publish
>   cd ../kn-datatable && npm publish
>   cd ../kn-dropdown && npm publish
>   cd ../kn-footer && npm publish
>   cd ../kn-minicards && npm publish
>   cd ../kn-modal && npm publish
>   cd ../

- An then in the terminal:

```
~/node-packages$ source publish
```

---

So actually, the extension doesn't really matter too.